# Silverlight and TCP

Tags: silverlight

Is it possible for Siverlight to communicate directly with an open TCP port on the user's machine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in a word No.

You can use [sockets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc296248%28VS.95%29.aspx)  (and therefore TCP) to communicate with open ports (in a limited range) on the server that is hosting the application, but you cannot connect to any other machines.  if you need to interoperate with something on the client machine i would suggest using the new COM interoperability in Silverlight 4 ([here](http://sblakemore.com/blog/post/Silverlight-4-COM-Automation-e28093-Taking-photos-with-a-DSLR-using-Windows-Image-Acquisition.aspx) is an example)

Comment: I guess I can talk to the server and have that bounce back to the client. There are no firewall issues, so it should work.

Comment: what are you trying to communicate with on the client machine?

Comment: An old Windows application written in VB 6. Since VB6 can display web pages I thought that it could also display Silverlight apps. But it needs to be able to raise events in the host and this was the only thing I could think of.

Comment: you could probably use javascript as a bridge language.  js<--> sl is pretty easy and im sure there is a way for Vb to listen to js events in its hosted document.

Comment: If you're using COM interoperability or P/Invoke, you already assume elevated privileges. In that case, there are no such restrictions as you claim. The answer is yes, not no.

Answer (score 0):

You can connect to an open TCP port on any machine that serves a security policy file or to any machine, including the local client, if Silverlight runs with elevated privileges.

Elevated privileges are not likely to be problematic as in scenarios like this you are probably developing a line of business application.

At my company I implemented the binary TCP protocol of an RFID server in Silverlight. The server must be connected to the local network and its dns name (or ip address) be known, other than that there is no problem in doing this sort of thing. It is around since Silverlight 3.